# How to restart Supervisor from putty?

Tags: supervisord

My server with supervisor worked fine. I just moved my files to different directory. After moving that specific supervisor is not working. I revert my changes but still not working.

I used putty and winscp for this.

Any Solution????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved. I restarted the server and now supervisord working fine.
The problem is when I moved my files to different directory, then I accidentally delete the supervisord.pid from tmp directory.